# How to modify tagList input from a list to individual tags

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am using the following code to create a list of independent radioButtons in my R shiny app.

```
    req(files_list_creator_1())
    numVar <- asInt(length(files_list_creator_1()))
    print(numVar)
    
    taglist = list(radioButtons(inputId = "file_num", label ="File number", choices = c("Choices will appear here")))
    for (i in 1:numVar){
      taglist = append(taglist, list(radioButtons(inputId = paste("x_var_of_file", i, sep ="_") , label = paste("x Variables of file", i, sep = "-"), choices = c("Choices will appear here"))))
      taglist = append(taglist, list(radioButtons(inputId = paste("y_var_of_file", i, sep ="_") , label = paste("y Variables of file", i, sep = "-"), choices = c("Choices will appear here"))))
      print(taglist)
      
    }
tagList(taglist)
})
```

Here files_list_creator_1() is a reactive server function that reads the excel files uploaded by a user as dataframes, and then combines them into a list and returns this list as its output.

On running the code, the app loads without any error, but the list of radioButtons is not visible. Can someone please help out with the issue? I am using uiOutput("Variables") to output the radioButtons

tagList is an R function, and taglist is my own list in which I am storing the tags. I think the problem is that tagList is supposed to work as: tagList(tag1, tag2,....) whereas I am trying to make it work as: tagList(list(tag1,tag2,...)) How can I change this?

Here is the complete code with the relevant parts for a reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(here)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(checkmate)
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test App"),
  
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "Data",        
        fileInput("file_1", "Please choose Excel file", multiple = TRUE, accept = ".xlsx", buttonLabel = "Browse"),
        uiOutput("Variables")
        
      ),
      
      tabPanel(
        "Comparison Panel",

        
      )
      
      
    )
    
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  files_list_creator_1 <- reactive({
    files_list <- list()
    for (paths in input$file_1$datapath){  
      file_to_add <- as.data.frame(read_excel(paths))
      print(as.data.frame(read_excel(paths)))
      files_list <- append(files_list, list(file_to_add))
    
    }
    return(files_list) 
    
  })
#--------------------------------------------  
  output$variables <- renderUI({
    req(files_list_creator_1())
    numVar <- asInt(length(files_list_creator_1()))
    print(numVar)
    
    taglist = list(radioButtons(inputId = "file_num", label ="File number", choices = c("Choices will appear here")))
    for (i in 1:numVar){
      taglist = append(taglist, list(radioButtons(inputId = paste0("x_var_of_file", i, sep ="_") , label = paste("x Variables of file", i, sep = "-"), choices = c("Choices will appear here"))))
      taglist = append(taglist, list(radioButtons(inputId = paste0("y_var_of_file", i, sep ="_") , label = paste("y Variables of file", i, sep = "-"), choices = c("Choices will appear here"))))
      
    }
    do.call("tagList", taglist)
  })

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Have a look at `do.call`, i.e. try `do.call("tagList", list(tag1, tag2, ...))`

Comment: @stefan I tried do.call("tagList", taglist) as taglist is my list(tag1, tag2,....) but it didn't work. There was no change from the previous situation

Comment: Hm. I had a second look, and IMHO even `tagList(taglist)` should work. I tried with a simple app `ui <- fluidPage( uiOutput("Variables")); server <- function(input, output, session) { output$Variables <- renderUI(tagList(taglist)) }; shinyApp(ui, server)`. Could you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with a working app code so that we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @stefan I have edited my original post and included the reproducible example there. Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: The issue with your above example is, that you are using `uiOutput("Variables")` (uppercase "V") along with `output$variables <- renderUI` (lowercase "v"). Accordingly, the output isn't rendered.

Comment: Thank you @ismirsehregal for pointing out the error

Answer (score 0):

Shiny's UI function accepts lists just fine (also without `renderUI` - do you really need it?). Please check the following *reproducible* example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("rbs")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$rbs <- renderUI({
    my_list_of_tags <- lapply(paste0("rb_", 1:10), function(x){radioButtons(inputId = x, label = x, choices = c("A", "B"))})
    # my_tagList <- do.call(tagList, my_list_of_tags) # not needed
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

**Edit:**
The issue with your above example is, that you are using `uiOutput("Variables")` (uppercase "V") along with `output$variables <- renderUI` (lowercase "v"). Accordingly, the output isn't rendered.

A fixed version of your code:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(here)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(checkmate)
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Test App"),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel(
        "Data",        
        fileInput("file_1", "Please choose Excel file", multiple = TRUE, accept = ".xlsx", buttonLabel = "Browse"),
        uiOutput("variables")
      ),
      tabPanel(
        "Comparison Panel"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  files_list_creator_1 <- reactive({
    files_list <- list()
    for (paths in input$file_1$datapath){  
      file_to_add <- as.data.frame(read_excel(paths))
      print(as.data.frame(read_excel(paths)))
      files_list <- append(files_list, list(file_to_add))
    }
    return(files_list) 
  })
  output$variables <- renderUI({
    req(files_list_creator_1())
    numVar <- asInt(length(files_list_creator_1()))
    print(numVar)
    taglist = list(radioButtons(inputId = "file_num", label ="File number", choices = c("Choices will appear here")))
    for (i in 1:numVar){
      taglist = append(taglist, list(radioButtons(inputId = paste0("x_var_of_file", i, sep ="_") , label = paste("x Variables of file", i, sep = "-"), choices = c("Choices will appear here"))))
      taglist = append(taglist, list(radioButtons(inputId = paste0("y_var_of_file", i, sep ="_") , label = paste("y Variables of file", i, sep = "-"), choices = c("Choices will appear here"))))
    }
    do.call("tagList", taglist)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I was using this method to begin with, and it was working, but the radioButtons were all linked, in that they weren't allowing me to select more than one option across different radioButtons. For example, if I selected choice A in button-1, then I wasn't allowed to select any choice in any other button. So I moved to the code that I posted above

Comment: @user22354047 well, as you can see this is not the case with my above example.